# How to disable all options from all menu that have the same value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I have multiple drop down menu on the same page. All these menu have the same class name (ie. .clientMenu). All menus have the same options exact options (ie. blue, yellow, white, black and green). My goal is to disable all value from all menus once one value is selects.

If I have 10 menus, then if the user select "blue" on any menu then "blue" should be disabled from the other 9 menus.  Therefore, "blue" can be selected in one menu only.

This is what I have tried but is not working. When I say it is not working I mean it is not disabling any option.

How can I get this code to work?

Thanks a bunch in advance

```
$('.clientMenu').change(function(){

    $(".clientMenu option").each(function(){

        if( $(this).val() == $(".clientMenu").val() )
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        else
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);

    });
});
```

EDITED
I have created a jsFiddle to make things easier
http://jsfiddle.net/24yhT/4/

Comment: the code looks fine, can we see the html or better a fiddle please?

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/24yhT/4/ it disable the ope option that the user select on the used menu. I need to to disable it on the 9 other menu and not on the one the the user selects

Comment: Consider caching the result of `$(".clientMenu").val()` and `$(this)` for better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can certainly make it shorter, not sure why yours wouldn't work though

```
function setOptionsDisabled($parent, val, disabled) {
  $parent.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('disabled', disabled);
  $parent.find('option[value="0"]').prop('disabled', false);
}
$('.clientMenu').change(function(){
  $others = $('.clientMenu').not(this);
  setOptionsDisabled($others, $(this).val(), true);
  setOptionsDisabled($others, $(this).data('val'), false);
  $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/24yhT/24/

Comment: how can I enable the option if the a user change the color? so you select blue all blues are disabled. from the same menu change blue to green. then I need blue to re-enabled..?

Comment: Made it so "Select an option" doesn't get disabled too, plus cleaned it up some.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you mark the element as disabled in the first `select`, `$(".clientMenu").val()` becomes `null` (disabled items are not considered valid selections, so you *lose* the value). The subsequent iterations never match on the value and so the `option`s are never disabled. One option is to store the value of the changed dropdown into a variable( `var val = $(this).val()` ) before looping through the options and compare against that instead. Are you sure you don't want to just want to disable the value in the *other* dropdowns? Right now your code disables that option in the change dropdown as well. You should probably filter out like this `$(".clientMenu").not(this).find("option")....`